# Traveling to London, UK in July, how to find cheap accommodation?

Tags: uk, london, accommodation, tips-and-tricks, hostels

I'm planning a trip to London, UK during early July and haven't been able to find any type of cheap (~15€/night/person for three nights) accommodation, preferably not that far from, or connected to in some form (metro, bus) to Victoria Station (where we get from and depart to the airport).

We're two friends that are travelling there and we'll meet with another (not living in London), so we'll need accommodation for three people for three days. Booking.com/KAYAK/ all give big star hotels or far, far away (>15km) inns **but none shows the typical Bed & Breakfast, Youth Hostels/Inns, or similar.**

We would prefer not to share a dorm with other people (because one of us snores a lot) but it's a possibility.

Airbnb is too expensive as in London city it lists almost only these kind of rent spaces with cozy beds and stuffed carpets.

**edit**

IS there any portal, website, or center, or place you know we could use, that usual travel portals do not list or filter?

Comment: It's likely that your plans have been misconceived.  This would explain why you are having difficulty. GBP 11 times 3 is GBP 33 with acco for 3 is unrealistic. Do you need a "formal" answer before the question is closed out as a WANTA question? http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1445/793

Comment: edited the question to fit. and note the ~ (around, average) meaning that it's not a problem it being 25 or 10 as long as it's not too far from it.

Comment: You might look at some of the resources for students studying in London. Some of the places that house them cheaply will have vacant rooms in Juljy.

Comment: where can i find them? thank you very much.

Comment: We don't do recommendations on here. try tripadvisor.

Your prices are unrealistic for London though - even a shared dorm at a Hostel is going to cost you more than that.

@PatriciaShanahan student halls tend to make quite comfortable rooms - it'a almost certainly going to cost more than a hostel.

Comment: all i've found is over 38€/30-35gbp , but all were hotels / hostels, which is way over than most european cities., there must be something lower for students / young  people.

Comment: @CMaster Things may have changed since the 1960's, when I was a student in London, but at that time a Hall of Residence place was a prize - I had one for about a year. The rest of the time I lived in much less comfortable private accommodation. Generally, the college and university halls are used in the summer for conference accommodation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan they are cheap (~160 a week, so 22 the night, which is Really fine), but they just offer weekly rent ( we're gonna stay 3 nights only) .

Comment: You should be looking in Ilford, Seven Kings, and Chadwell Heath near the national rail stations.

Comment: @CptEric No, London is just that expensive. (Although it's not very different in Paris)

Comment: Can you [bring a tent](http://www.visitlondon.com/where-to-stay/caravan-and-camping)?  £14.00 per pitch at 20 km from central London, or twice that amount closer to the centre.

Comment: no, thought we could buy a cheap one on primark / decathlon / poundland once there. that's a great idea! didn't think of that.

Comment: hi @CptEric  Something to consider is that London is literally one of the top three most expensive places on Earth for accommodation, and indeed all other expenses.  (You'll be stunned at the cost of transport, etc.) Second fact, it's the worst place on Earth.  If you're young, cool, people (without much money on hand) perhaps it's worth considering for a moment - why go to London in particular?  The three of you have a collection of incredible places you could go in Europe or even in the UK. London today's just a city for billionaires to have $5000 lunches.

Comment: @JoeBlow  because we go there to visit the 3rd one who lives near it, basically, not a "let's go to london because reasons" trip :(   it still has some "cheap", ~25gbp/night  alternatives as i've seen on some comments, and that's pretty fine for us.

Comment: hi @CptEric.  I see.  There's no chance you two could stay with your buddy?  Get a blow-up mattress and sleep on the floor you know.  I hope you enjoy anyway!

Comment: He's accomodated with a family there :(

Comment: @JoeBlow Did an oligarch spill your pint or something? London is unquestionably one of the greatest cities in the world.

Comment: @JoeBlow There are many [free things to do in London](http://www.visitlondon.com/things-to-do/budget-london/101-free-things-to-do-in-london).

Comment: No problem @CptEric ! It is a good list, there's a few things on there I didn't know about, and I live here. ;)

Comment: hi @AE ! - all of the "free" things mentioned would cost from 50 to 500 dollars in transport to get to and from, depending on group size and where you're staying.    Say the idea is: "A city visit, where one visits free museums."  Literally, on the whole planet, the most expensive choice one could make for that concept - is London!   :O  By a huge margin.

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow, cycle hire is [free for up to 30 minutes, £2 for a 24 hour period](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/cycling/santander-cycles/what-you-pay). Buses are [£1.50 per journey](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/fares/bus-and-tram) and get priority over other traffic. Travel on the Tube (London Underground) as much as you like for [£6.50 per day (central London), £7.60 per day gets you out to the suburbs](http://content.tfl.gov.uk/adult-fares.pdf). My experience of public transport fares in other world capitals (Paris, Tokyo, Washington) is pretty similar.

Comment: (US$500 is enough for you to go [from London to Paris and back again 5 times](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/calendar/eurostar-deals/eurostar-promotion/p?intcmp_hp_pos1_paris_brussels_29_DitchTheDietInStyle_blue=) and still have money left over).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40377/discussion-on-question-by-cpteric-traveling-to-uk-london-in-july-how-to-find).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the Youth Hostel Association:

http://www.yha.org.uk/places-to-stay/london

Central London beds from £15/person/night - not quite as cheap as you asked for but probably one of the cheapest you're likely to get, short of a tent or a homeless shelter.

Actually, looking on Airbnb there are a couple of places offering beds for as low as £7, and a couple of them are in what I'd consider central London. Use the price filter to find them, and I suspect you'll need to book way ahead of time.

https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/London--United-Kingdom?price_max=8

Update: I'm looking at Airbnb again later the same day and the central London places I saw offering beds for for £7 are no longer showing as listed - perhaps because they're all booked up? I don't know. There's still a few places showing at that price in outer London - but I guess the moral is that it's worth checking airbnb more than once because places go in and out of availability, even if you're not searching for specific dates.

Comment: No reason to restrict to YHA only. Any hostel organisation would do.

Comment: An interesting question these days is "What is cheaper, youth hostels, or the AirBNB option?"

Comment: will look at it and at similar things. i didn't know YHA existed. will look at airB&B too, i discarded it at first because i saw over 60gpb places when i first looked at it a week ago.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, i found a YHA related website with more youth hostels and they are damn cheap! accepted :P